# how to stop a youtube video emebed in iframe playing, when slider rotates and when tab is inactive?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develop a web page which contains ajax-tabs. In the tabs section I am using the galleryview slider. There are 5 tabs; the first tab contains an image gallery, the next tab contains a video gallery, the third and fourth contain text, and the last tab contains the image gallery.

My problem is that when I switch from one tab to other the YouTube video which is currently playing doesn't stop playing. I tried the YouTube api but it is not working.

IF I AM SWITCHING FORM VIDEOS TAB TO GALLERY/PROFILE/ADS TABS,THE VIDEO IS NOT STOPPING. PLEASE PROVIDE ME THE SOLUTION.I WOULD APPRECIATE YOUR HELP.

This is my code

```
    <div class="tabs">
      <ul class="tabNavigation">
        <li><a class="selected" href="#first">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a class="" href="#second">VIDEOS</a></li>
        <li><a class="" href="#third">PROFILE</a></li>
        <li><a class="" href="#fourth">FILMOGRAPHY</a></li>
        <li><a class="" href="#fifth">ADS &amp; EVENTS</a></li>
      </ul>

    <!--FIRST SECTION START-->

    <div style="display: block; padding:0px; width:478px;" id="first">

     <div id="gallery_wrap"> 
<div class="galleryview"> 
<div id="photos">

<div class="panel">
 <img src="Profile/big/slide-d01.jpg"  />
</div>
<div class="panel">
 <img src="Profile/big/slide-d02.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="panel">
<img src="Profile/big/slide-d03.jpg" />
</div>


 <div class="slider-bg">
 <ul class="filmstrip"> 
      <li><img src="Profile/thumb/sd1.jpg" alt="" /></li> 
      <li><img src="Profile/thumb/sd2.jpg" alt="" /></li> 
      <li><img src="Profile/thumb/sd3.jpg" alt="" /></li> 

</ul>
</div> 
</div><!--photos--> 
</div><!--galleryview--> 
 </div> <!--gallerywrap-->       
  </div><!--first-->
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--FIRST SECTION END-->



    <!--SECOND SECTION START-->


<div id="second"> 
<div id="gallery_wrap"> 
<div id="photos1" class="galleryview"> 

<div class="panel">
<iframe width="454" height="253" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rVv9y6J84q8?HD=1;rel=0;showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" ></iframe>
</div>

    <div class="panel">
<iframe width="454" height="253" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/BcwVZTWu9sU?HD=1;rel=0;showinfo=0;enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" ></iframe>
</div>

    <div class="panel">
<iframe  width="454" height="253" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DwjbC1z2yjw?HD=1;rel=0;showinfo=0;enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always"  frameborder="0" ></iframe>
</div>


<div class="slider-bg">
<ul class="filmstrip"> 
    <li><img src="Profile/thumb/gopichand.png" alt="" /></li> 
    <li><img src="Profile/thumb/manoj.png" alt="" /></li> 
    <li><img src="Profile/thumb/vikram.png" alt="" /></li> 

</ul>
</div>

</div><!--photos--> 
</div><!--gallerywrap-->  

    </div><!--second-->

    <!--SECOND SECTION END-->

    <!--THRID SECTION START-->

    <div style="display: none;" id="third">

    <p> 'Fresh Face title'.</p>
    <p>Born on February 14 1990 in Delhi, </p>
    <p>She made it to top 10 finalists and went on to become a model. </p>
    <p> opposite Vikram.</p>

    </div>

    <!--THRID SECTION END-->

    <!--FOURTH SECTION START-->

    <div style="display: none;" id="fourth">

    <p>film Vedam (2010).</p>
            <span><a href="" target="_blank">More>></a></span>


    </div>

    <!--FOURTH SECTION END-->

    <!--FIFTH SECTION START-->

    <div style="display: none;" id="fifth">
     <!--
   <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable </p> -->

    </div>

    <!--FIFTH SECTION END-->


</div>


<!-- profileright-sec End --></div>
```

Comment: I have similar issue , Instead of clicking tab or slider . I have drop-down menu , from which I need to select embedded videos to play , If I am playing one and switch to next , the older audio ll be playing simultaneously . Please Help Us out here . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you click for the next video using this code

```
$('#videoid').get(0).stopVideo();
```

if you going to first video to second one `onclick` of the second video's tab try like this

```
 $('#video1').get(0).stopVideo();
```

Note: Its using Jquery

Comment: Thanks for the response.but its not working.I am adding my code please go through.

Comment: I tried this , but I am getting error as undefined function for stopVideo() . I believe this works for the video embedded using object/swfobject . Not for Iframes . onStop() will work partially though .

Comment: @krish How does css file would help . this issue is basically on javascript.